# RSS XML not working in IE works in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: sql-server, xml, internet-explorer, rss

I am using [this](http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/) plugin, with the xml feed. I have a SP that generates xml file for this news feed and saves it in the desired location. Here is the SQL query for the same

```
SET @fileName = 'D:\YVXS\Ycube-Templates\SSTool\output\include\YNews\ycube.xml'
SET @sqlStr = 'select ''<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?> <rss version=""2.0""> <channel> <title> SiteName </title> <description> Site Description </description> <link> http://www.website.com </link>'' + (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(TITLE)) AS title,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[PUB DATE],101) AS pubdate, ''dbo_News_view.php?editid1='' + cast([Sl No] as varchar(20)) AS link, ''dbo_News_list.php?dbo_New_list.aspx?'' AS [guid] FROM SSTOOL.DBO.NEWS item FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS) + (SELECT ''</channel> </rss>'')'
SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "'+@sqlStr+'" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -S "LOCALHOST\SQLSERVER" -U "sa" -P "source$1" -w -r -t -x'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd
```

Everything works as expected in chrome and Firefox, however in IE news ticker shows blank content. When I manually open the xml file and save it (notepad) without any changes, news ticker starts working in IE as expected.
The above SP generates xml exactly as mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS#Example)

Comment: Please note that i not doing any changes in the xml file, I open it in a notepad and just save it, post which the news ticker plugin starts working in IE as well

Comment: Huh!! to clarify it more (to some stupid down-voters) I have found the problem is pertaining to encoding in Server R2, the query out is unnecessarily adding "ÿþ" and can be viewed in "view-source" from IE pages (not in chrome or XML file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And just as i thought, the problem was with encoding only. The stuff was difficult for me to understand as the main xml file was not showing any "unwanted" characters. I took a long way of analyzing the binary copy of the xml file but the problem became obvious when I checked the source of html file from withing Internet Explorer (as chrome source was also absolutely ok, and seems that only IE was having encoding problem).

Just by adding -c -C850 in the bcp statement I am able to render XML with correct encoding..

Here is my final solution

```
SET @fileName = 'D:\YVXS\Ycube-Templates\SSTool\output\include\YNews\ycube.xml'
SET @sqlStr = 'select ''<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?> <rss version=""2.0""> <channel> <title> SiteName </title> <description> Site Description </description> <link> http://www.website.com </link>'' + (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(TITLE)) AS title,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[PUB DATE],101) AS pubdate, ''dbo_News_view.php?editid1='' + cast([Sl No] as varchar(20)) AS link, ''dbo_News_list.php?dbo_New_list.aspx?'' AS [guid] FROM SSTOOL.DBO.NEWS item FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS) + (SELECT ''</channel> </rss>'')'
SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "'+@sqlStr+'" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -S "LOCALHOST\SQLSERVER" -U "sa" -P "source$1" -r -t -x -c -C850'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd
```